# How to calculate rise time of linear regulator

Tags: power, voltage-regulator

Given a standard LDO with no soft start, that provides power to a bunch of decoupling capacitors, and a single chip.   How do you calculate the rise time of the output rail ahead of time?  Is it based on the time constant of the Rds of the internal FET into the decoupling capacitors and somehow minus the current draw of the part?

I don't really see the Rds spec'd in the datasheets I've looked at.

Comment: Largely a function of capacitance. Yor may need to start with how long it takes to charge the input-side capacitor to the dropout voltage. Below that it isn't even regulating, and you will get hum through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reasonable guess would be to multiply the decoupling capacitance times the output voltage and divide by the output current limit. In most cases the current limit will probably be high enough that you can ignore the load current.

Expect it to be on the optimistic side if the load capacitance is very low and it thus predicts rise times in microseconds or less.

Comment: I thought the current limit was more of a do not exceed this number or it'll break number?  Will a linear regulator always restrict it's current flow to the rated limit?

Comment: Linear regulators have a lot of protections built in and a current limit is one of them. At university we used to call them the student proof chips - very hard to break.

Comment: @confused The peak current will be limited internally on just about every monolithic regulator. If you design your own it might not have that feature and you'd have to estimate the maximum current- eg. use something like the Idss of the pass MOSFET,

Comment: Thank you, this is good advice.  I must need to go back to school I didn't get at first that V*C is charge, and V*C/I is time.

Comment: Would this be true for a buck switcher too?

Comment: @confused Yes. It should be true for any regulator where the output current (when overloaded) is more-or-less constant.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly from my university days ( a long time ago), it takes about 4 (four) time constants for the voltage to rise to the maximum value.

It's exponential, asymptotic if I recall, so it never actually gets to the maximum.
Something like 3 or 4 time constants is about close enough.

So you'd need to calculate or determine what the source resistance is that's driving the capacitors.
Might be a bit hard to find, but a full blown datasheet for the regulator should have it as it determines the maximum output current.

Alternatively, build a circuit with the regulator and decoupling capacitors and use a digital storage oscilloscope to measure the rise time.